# How to associate a value to a function call?

Tags: c#

Many times I had to do stuff similar to this:

```
if (value == certainValueA) call functionA()
if (value == certainValueB) call functionB()
```

I've always done it like this. However now I have over 50 cases like this, and this way seems bad.

I'd like a more efficient way to do it. The solution is probably well documented, but so far the combination of words I'm using to find such a things doesn't return any interesting results.

I mostly need a direction on what to look into.

Comment: The functions to call have all the same signature?

Comment: in the current case yes, but I have some case in the base that they didn't

Comment: Have you considered having a map with your values of interest as the index (or keys, if they're not integers) and the functions as your values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a Dictionary filled with delegates; something like:

```
var dispatch = new Dictionary<TypeOfValue, Action>() {
    { certainValueA, () => functionA() },
    { certainValueB, () => functionB() },
};

TypeOfValue value = // get value here   

dispatch[value]();
```

Comment: Are you sure the values are not being invoked? Shouldn't it be `() => functionA` (notice no parentheses)?

Comment: The values are not being invoked when declaring the dictionary, because `() => ` is defining an Action, not invoking it. You could actually also say `{ certainValueA, functionA }` - which would work the same.

Comment: Got it. I had your 2nd example in mind. Thanks for clarifying the 1st case.

Comment: How to solve the problem of different signatures (thus different Action<T> to be invoked)?

Comment: Depends whether you can fill those parameters when you define the dictionary, or only as you invoke the action. In the first case, just plug them into the invocation in the dictionary definition, and they're still just `Action` from the outside. In the second case, well, it will depend on the details, I think. You'll probably need to refactor a bit.

Comment: Well, no I haven't find a way to call it with your code. The dictionary defines an Action without values so you cannot call _dispatch[value](X);_ Suppose that functionB wants an integer as input parameter. How do you call it from dispatch?

Comment: If every function in the Dictionary takes an integer, you define the action as `Action<int>`. If they're all different, and need parameters at invoke-time, then you have custom logic per invocation, and so you need custom code per invocation - there's no way around that. You could put that custom code in the `Action`, if you can have it pull the parameters from somewhere, I suppose. Like I said, the solution would depend on the details of your code.